# How to setup the Workspace authentication to work with SSO for Oracle APEX Server?

Tags: oracle, single-sign-on, oracle-apex

I have installed APEX server and now I would like to know the next steps in this process to setup the Workspace authentication to work with SSO. How can I set up SSO on apex server??

Comment: You should post the code of your attempt to do it and highlight any issues.  Then we can help you modify what you have attempted to get it working :)

Comment: What authentication scheme are you using? If for example, you are using HTTP Header Variable or LDAP authentication, then make sure you add an administrative username that the authentication scheme resolves APP_USER to.

Comment: I thought to try out with LDAP,I was able to do setup LDAP but my account got locked after I selected "Select the 
 Make Current Scheme option"

Comment: I did try to  alter the schema and run the SP but again its now set to default and not LDAP                                          
SQL> ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA APEX_180200;

Session altered.

SQL> BEGIN
  2  apex_instance_admin.set_parameter('APEX_BUILDER_AUTHENTICATION','APEX');
  3  END;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> exit

Answer (score 0):

[image: Important Notice]

Says here very clearly that you need to make sure that whatever your APP_USER resolves to, matches with an account in your workspace or you risk locking yourself out. The usual ADMIN account is probably not going to work.